# Why is money offered to God as ₹101, 1001 etc. and not ₹ 100, 1000 etc?

Tags: temple, worship, superstitions, priests

I have noticed that after performing rituals, Hindus give dakshina (or fees) to the pandit (priest) in the form of ₹ 101, 151, 501 or ₹ 1001  and not ₹ 100, 150, 500 or simply any round figure. Even in the temples the money offered to the god (Hundi) is ₹ 101, 151, 1001 etc. What is the reason behind adding that one rupee to that round figure (₹1000 + ₹1)?

Comment: Not only Hinduism does this. Question not about Hindu religion.